# Fit Plotly Subplot in Bootstrap Card

Tags: r, bootstrap-4, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

In the reproducible code below plot 1 looks fine in terms of its width/height, but I'd like to expand plot 2 in terms of its height so the subplots don't seem so "squished" together. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to do that so it stays nicely within the card but expands responsively with the number of subplots? In this example, there are five subplots, but that could be any number (usually 2 to 7 or so).

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(plotly)

card <- function(body, title) {
  div(class = "card",
    div(icon("chart-line", style = "color:white"), class = "card-header bg-success text-white text-center font-weight-bold", title),
    div(class = "card-body d-flex justify-content-center", body)
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(

    navbarPage(
        theme = bs_theme(bootswatch = "flatly", version = 4),
        title = 'Methods',
        tabPanel('One'),
    ),
    mainPanel(
        h1('Hello World'),      
        
    uiOutput('p1'),
    br(),
    uiOutput('p2'),

        
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$p1 <- renderUI({
        fig <- plot_ly(data = iris, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Petal.Length)
        card(fig, 'Plot 1: Looks Good')
    })

    
    ### I could do this
    output$p2 <- renderUI({
    vars <- setdiff(names(economics), "date")
    plots <- lapply(vars, function(var) {
      plot_ly(economics, x = ~date, y = as.formula(paste0("~", var))) %>%
        add_lines(name = var)
    })  
        card(subplot(plots, nrows = length(plots), shareX = TRUE, titleX = FALSE), 'Plot 2: Too Squished')
    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `plotlyOutput` and pass a `height` parameter corresponding to the number of subplots:

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(plotly)

card <- function(body, title) {
  div(class = "card",
      div(icon("chart-line", style = "color:white"), class = "card-header bg-success text-white text-center font-weight-bold", title),
      div(class = "card-body d-flex justify-content-center", body)
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage(
    theme = bs_theme(bootswatch = "flatly", version = 4),
    title = 'Methods',
    tabPanel('One'),
  ),
  mainPanel(
    h1('Hello World'),
    uiOutput('p1'),
    br(),
    uiOutput('p2'),
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$p1 <- renderUI({
    fig <- plot_ly(data = iris, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Petal.Length)
    card(fig, 'Plot 1: Looks Good')
  })
  
  output$plotlyOut <- renderPlotly({
    vars <- setdiff(names(economics), "date")
    plots <- lapply(vars, function(var) {
      plot_ly(economics, x = ~date, y = as.formula(paste0("~", var))) %>%
        add_lines(name = var)
    })  
    subplot(plots, nrows = length(plots), shareX = TRUE, titleX = FALSE)
  })
  
  output$p2 <- renderUI({
    nSubplots <- length(setdiff(names(economics), "date"))
    card(plotlyOutput("plotlyOut", height = paste0(nSubplots*200, "px")), 'Plot 2: Looks Good?')
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: result]

Comment: Do you know if it's possible for an `plotly` actual plot to inherit a theme? I see you can do this in python here https://hellodash.pythonanywhere.com/. The plot will change to a dark background if a dark theme is selected. Can we do this in R?

Comment: @kraggle I'm not aware of a solution for `plot_ly()`, however you can use the [thematic](https://rstudio.github.io/thematic/) package on `ggplotly`. Also check this [related article](https://plotly.com/r/styling-figures/).

Comment: Right. I was hoping this would work for the interactive. Apparently not supported as of yet. Thanks!

Comment: @kraggle `ggplotly()` is based on a `ggplot` but also results in an interactive `plotly` object.

Comment: Right. I’m using strictly R ‘plotly::plot_ly’